# Validation in android edittext skipping to else statment

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I have a if statement attached to my onClick listener for a button, however, the if statement always skips to else part of the statement even if the text matches the if part of the statement, any help please;

```
findActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (activityFinder.getText().equals("NEW ACTIVITY".toLowerCase())){
                    startActivity(new Intent(NewActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                } else if (activityFinder.getText().equals("")){
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Activity does not exist", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "We are working on creating this activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: probably some space is available so try it as `activityFinder.getText().toString().trim()`

Comment: Try
if (activityFinder.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnorCase("NEW ACTIVITY"))

Comment: Cheers :) that solved it. Quick quetion what does trim do?

Answer (score 0):

As told in comments use `activityFinder.getText().toString().trim()`

`trim()` removes any extra space from your string

See this documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()